# What's the difference between "number" and Number in javascript when iterating over an object?

Tags: javascript, object, types

here's an object.

```
let menu = {
  width: 200,
  height: 300,
  title: "My menu"
};
```

that's the right code

```
function multiplyNumeric(obj) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] == 'number') {
      obj[key] *= 2;
    }
  }
}
```

and here's my code

```
function multiplyNumeric(obj) {
      for (let key in obj) {
        if (typeof(obj[key]) === Number) {
          obj[key] *= 2;
        }
      }
    }
```

Please tell me what makes the difference?

Comment: `typeof(obj[key]) === Number` is just equivalent to `false` because `typeof` always returns a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `typeof` operator returns a string containing the name of the type of the operand. `Number` is a function that converts its input to a number.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `'number'` is an string and `Number` is an build-in function.

```
console.log(typeof "number") //string
console.log(typeof Number) //function
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jonas Høgh pointed out `Nummer` is a JavaScript function

A quick examlple of understanding the `Number` function:

```js
console.log(Number(true));
console.log(Number(false));
console.log(Number(new Date()));
console.log(Number("999"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The Number() is Javascript function converts the object argument to a number that represents the object's value.
If the value cannot be converted to a legal number, NaN is returned.

`typeof(obj[key])` function returns, what kind of type the value is, like 'number' and string etc